# Fatal error in dictionary - Index out of range / Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a txt text file. The text file contains the text attached to each date.

Example:

> 30.10.2022 : Hello Stack Overflow.

> 31.10.2022 : Hello programmers.

> 01.11.2022 : We are the best.

> 02.11.2022 : Swift, is the best programming language.

etc…

I need to bind each sentence to date and show only the sentence that corresponds to today's date.

Example:

> If today is 30.10.2022 - show in textView only the result: Hello Stack Overflow. And the same for every day... If the date changes from 30.10.2022 to 31.10.2022, we will see the result in textView - Hello programmers!

I tried to split my text from file text to dictionary and got an error - Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:575: Fatal error: Index out of range.

I want to note that yesterday everything was working, but today it is not working, despite the fact that I did not change the code. Got confused. I can't understand what I missed.

**Code with error...**

---

```
import Foundation

class NameDaysModel {

private var dataArray: [String] = []

func loadDictionary() -> Dictionary<String, String> {
    
    let pathToFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "NameDays", ofType: "txt")

    if let path = pathToFile {
        let countriesString = try! String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        dataArray = countriesString.components(separatedBy: "\n")
    }
    
    var dictionary = [String: String]()
    for line in dataArray {
        let components = line.components(separatedBy: " : ")
        dictionary[components[0]] = components[1] // = Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range
    }
    
    return dictionary
}
   
private func getDate() -> String {
    
    let date = NSDate()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
    let str = dateFormatter.string(from: date as Date)
    return str
}

func getNameDay() -> String {
    let date = getDate()
    let nameDays = loadDictionary()
    return nameDays["\(date)"] ?? ""
}
}
```

---

Comment: My guess is that you have an empty line in the file, which obviously won't contain `:`.

Comment: Even an empty line at the end can cause the crash. To avoid it add a `where` clause: `for line in dataArray where line contains(" : ") {`. And don't use `NSDate` in Swift. The native equivalent is `Date()` or `Date.now`

Comment: @Sulthan Hi!) You were right! When I edited the txt file through Xcode it created the last empty line and through the editor in Xcode I can't delete it. I had to edit it through textEdit, and also give read-only permission in the properties.

Comment: @vadian Hi!) You are right too! If you want, you can write a complete answer with the code, I will approve. Note - I can't use Date.now because it's supported in iOS 15... I'm still forced to support iOS 14...

Comment: `Date()` works also in iOS 14 (Swift 3 and later)

Comment: @vadian Thank you very much!) I changed it to Date(). Why do you not recommend using NSDate?)

Comment: Because it's a Objective-C class and you should not use those classes if there is a native Swift (struct) equivalent. By the way delete also the redundant cast `as Date`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error you're getting, it sounds like some of the lines in your text file don't contain the string " : ". In that case your `components` array from the line `let components = line.components(separatedBy: " : ")` would only contain 1 element: The entire line of text.

You need to either make sure your data always contains a " : " in every line or add checking code that makes sure each value of `components` contains at least 2 elements before attempting to index into `components[1]`.

Comment: Hi!) Thanks for your reply!) I just checked. I deleted all lines from the text file except for the four that I mentioned in the question above. The error did not disappear...((